# Como evitar superposición de texto sobre contador de caracteres dentro de un TextArea

Tags: html, css, web, webforms

Tengo un problema con un *text area* en **HTML**, el problema es que el *text area* tiene un contador de caracteres dentro del mismo, funciona bien y se ve de esta manera.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EL *problema* es que cuando se llega a cierto de **limite** de caracteres, el valor del **textarea** se *superpone* a este contador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Es importante recalcar que esto solo sucede cuando se escriben **palabras** de una cantidad *enorme de caracteres*, lo cual es poco probable.

Aun *asi*, quisiera saber si existe una *solución* a esto (tal vez solo por curiosidad).

Si alguien sabe algo de esto seria genial que me diera su opinion.

> Estoy usando Angular 8 en caso de que pueda existir una solucion con este framework.

```
<textarea rows="5" placeholder="Ingresa tus comentarios" [(ngModel)]="mensajeContacto" maxlength="800" 
class="contact-textarea-container " 
[ngClass]="{'contact-textarea-error': errorMensaje}">
</textarea>
 <span>{{mensajeContacto.length}}/800</span>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu codigo.

Comment: Podrías añadirle un padding a tu textarea

Comment: Si estas usando CSS para poner el contador encima del textarea deberías agregarlo para poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: Al span ponle un style="margin-top:20px"

Answer (score 1):

En principio, con CSS no se puede modificar el "padding-bottom" del texto dentro del textarea, mi sugerencia es añadir un contenedor y mostrar la etiqueta "xxx/800" justo debajo del textarea, flotando a la derecha, algo como:

```
<div class="container">
  <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Ingresa tus comentarios" [(ngModel)]="mensajeContacto" maxlength="800" class="contact-textarea-container" [ngClass]="{'contact-textarea-error': errorMensaje}"></textarea>
  <span style="float: right; margin-top: -2px">{{mensajeContacto.length}}/800</span>
<div>
```

El css del container quizás tendrías que definirlo para determinar el tamaño u otros parámetros, aunque no es estrictamente necesario, depende.